# Excel Options button "grayed out"

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to access File > Options I get something like this:

[image]

Does someone know how can I enable the Options button via VBA?

What I have tried so far:

```
Sub enableOptionButton()
    Application.CommandBars("Options").Enabled = True
    Application.CommandBars("Tools").Enabled = True
    Application.CommandBars("File").Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the worksheet somehow protected?

Comment: Some sheets are protected

Comment: For curiosity's sake, what happens if you unprotect all of them in the workbook? Does it give you the `Options` then?

Comment: What kind of a workbook is it?

Comment: It is a .xlsb workbook, if I understood you correctly

Comment: The menus in the most recent versions of Office are controlled through Ribbon XML. Ribbon XML in a workbook or in an Add-in can change the default UI - there's nothing you can do about this with VBA. The CommandBars object model doesn't affect Ribbon controls. You need to figure out where this Ribbon XML is coming from that's changing your interface. Begin by starting Excel in "Safe Mode" and see if the restriction is gone.

Comment: If the "Options" are available in Safe Mode, go to the Developer tab in the Ribbon and look in the Add-ins and COM Add-ins dialog boxes. You can uncheck what's there, one-by-one, until you find the culprit. If you still can't find it, then you've installed a machine-wide Add-in (rather than per-User) and will have to look in the Control Panel "Programs" for add-ins and uninstall it/them.

Comment: Thank you very much @Cindy Meister, I changed the Ribbon XML and got the options button back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menus in the most recent versions of Office are controlled through Ribbon XML. Ribbon XML in a workbook or in an Add-in can change the default UI - there's nothing you can do about this with VBA. The CommandBars object model doesn't affect Ribbon controls.

So you need to figure out what's changing the Ribbon XML - could be Ribbon XML that's part of a workbook or part of an Add-in - and change that Ribbon XML or remove the add-in.